# if statement in a array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a data which im posting using cURL. Now i was wondering if i can pass 2 variables for 1 array.

This is the code that im using to send data

```
$data = [
    'completion_date'       =>  '31/03/2019',
    'customer_id'           =>  80,
    'full_name'             =>  '',
    'email_address'         =>  'email@email.com',
    'telephone'             =>  '012122212',
    'mobile'                =>  '0787878',
    'address'               =>  'Line 1 address'.chr(10).'Line 2 address',
    'city'                  =>  'City',
    'county'                =>  'County',
    'postcode'              =>  'Postcode',
    'site_company_name'     =>  'Site Company Name',
    'site_full_name'        =>  'Site Contact Name',
    'site_telephone'        =>  '012121212',
    'site_mobile'           =>  '07878787',
    'site_fax'              =>  'Depreciated, not in use',
    'site_email_address'    =>  'email@email.com',
    'site_address'          =>  'Site Line 1 address'.chr(10).'Line 2 address',
    'site_city'             =>  'Site City',
    'site_county'           =>  'Site County',
    'site_postcode'         =>  'Site Postcode',
    'site_notes'            =>  'Site Notes',
    'customer_ref'          =>  $RecordID,
    'wo_ref'                =>  'Customer Job Ref',
    'po_ref'                =>  $OrderID,
    'short_description'     =>  'short description of job',
    'description'           =>  'long description of job',
    'customer_notes'        =>  'Customer notes',
    'job_products'          =>  json_encode($job_products)
];
```

now i was wondering if i can do something like this

```
'customer_notes'        =>  $variable1 or $variable2,
```

what im trying to accomplish is if the `$variable1` is empty use data from `$variable2` and the other way around. is there a way of doing it or not really ?

```
'full_name'=> if $var1 empty use $var2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use ternary operator

```
'customer_notes' => !empty($variable1) ? $variable1 : $variable2,
```

Comment: when used for certain arrays it gives me `Ouch.
Server Error: 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Is that array similar to this one?

Comment: When im using your code it gives me error 500 intenal server error, but i have no error log to investigate it

Comment: I have just replaced the value for the key with if empty and boom

Comment: pls show what you have exactly done.

Comment: `'full_name'     =>  !empty($Name) ? $Name : $iName,` you can find my full code and the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906658/why-am-i-getting-ouch-server-error-500-internal-server-error-no-error-log?noredirect=1#comment96580348_54906658)

Comment: that's too big.

Comment: well it gets ebay orders and posts them to job management software ( that was the idea but takes ages for me to figure out things )

Answer (score 1):

You can use anyone of them

```
'customer_notes' => !empty($variable1) ? $variable1 : $variable2,
```

or

```
'customer_notes' =>  $variable1 ?? $variable2, (PHP 7)
```

Comment: can u please mention the PHP version for `??`